# Column information still present in sstables after "drop column"

Tags: cassandra

We are running Cassandra 3.11.4 (yes, I know it's old - we will upgrade soon).

We have unfortunately run into an issue where I am doing restore/PITR that fails to do "nodetool refresh" on a specific table, as the sstable(s) contain column information that should no longer be present, as these (3) columns have been dropped 4 months ago.
But "sstablemetadata " shows that they are still there.
Output/stacktrace is this:

```
nodetool refresh keyspace_name table_name
error: Unknown column reportspec during deserialization
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown column reportspec during deserialization
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SerializationHeader$Component.toHeader(SerializationHeader.java:326)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:522)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables(ColumnFamilyStore.java:788)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables(ColumnFamilyStore.java:726)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.loadNewSSTables(StorageService.java:5142)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:276)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Output from sstablemetadata shows the columns (reportparam, reportspec, transactionstarter) which have been dropped:

```
RegularColumns: {value7:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,76616c756537,646f6d61696e6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c6e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,646f63:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,756e69746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c756537:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), reportspec:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TupleType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), nodetype:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6e6f646574797065,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6465736372697074696f6e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), edge_parentid:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,656467655f706172656e746964,706172656e746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,73686172646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,6564676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6368696c646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,74736e74696d657374616d70:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), contextid:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e746578746964,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), contributordatapkidot:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e7472696275746f7264617461706b69646f74,736f757263656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,7265636f72646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6f626a656374747970656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), valuefilter:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,76616c756566696c746572,6175786964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,646f6d61696e6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c6e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), contributordata:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e7472696275746f7264617461,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7265636f7264726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6163746976697479:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,63726561746564617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,646f63:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,7265636f72646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,736f757263656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), edgeval:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6564676576616c,617474726964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6564676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), nodestate:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6e6f64657374617465,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,61737369676e65656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,646561646c696e65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,656e74727974696d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,707265767365716e6f61737369:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,707265767365716e6f7472616e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7072696f72697479:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,7374617465666c6f776964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,73746174656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,7461736b7374617475736964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7766656e74727974696d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType)), edge:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,65646765,6368696c646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6564676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,697374726565:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6c696e6b747970656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,706172656e746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7365716e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,73757070726573736564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType)), valuemodel:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,76616c75656d6f64656c,646f6d61696e6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c6e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,65787465726e616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), transitionlog:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,7472616e736974696f6e6c6f67,7374617465666c6f776964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6e6f64656e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType,7365716e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,61737369676e65656e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType,61737369676e656574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6475726174696f6e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6578656375746f726e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType,66726f6d7365716e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,66726f6d73746174656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6c6f6774696d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6c6f6774797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6d657373616765:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,737461747573666c61676964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,746f73746174656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), deleteop:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType, term:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,7465726d,70726f647563746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7465726d736c6973746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,737461727464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6d696e717479:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,656e6464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6d6178717479:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c65616474696d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c6f616474696d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6c6f7473697a65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7072696365:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,756e69746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), conv:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e76,6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636f6e766e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,636f6e7673746f70:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,636f6e76737472696e67:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,636f6e7674797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType)), workspaces:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,776f726b737061636573,776f726b:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,73656c776f726b:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), event:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6576656e74,71756575656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e7470617274736571:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e74736571:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e7474797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,63726561746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,75736572747970656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,686973746f72796964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6368616e67656c6f676964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6368616e6765726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,756e726561646576656e74736571:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e65787468696e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), key:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6b6579,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6b65796964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6b6579:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6b657974797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType)), contributordatahistory:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e7472696275746f7264617461686973746f7279,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7365716e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,637265617465646174656d696c6c6973:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f6465726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6f7065726174696f6e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,7265636f72646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,7265636f7264726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,736f757263656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), edge_edgeid:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,656467655f656467656964,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6368696c646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6564676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,74736e74696d657374616d70:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), shardedindexinfo:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,73686172646564696e646578696e666f,696e6465786b6579:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,696e6465786e756d626572:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6564697464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,666972737473686172646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,6e6577666972737473686172646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,6e65776e756d6265726f66736861726473:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,6e756d6265726f66736861726473:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,7374617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType)), domattrdetail:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,646f6d6174747264657461696c,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,636c61737376616c:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6672656574657874:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,686d7374797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,696e757365:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6d756c746976616c7565:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,72657669736564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,756e69746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c696461746f72:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), contributordatarevision:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e7472696275746f72646174617265766973696f6e,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6564697464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,66697273747265636f7264726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c61746573747265636f7264726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7265636f72646964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,736f757263656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), format:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,666f726d6174,666f726d61746e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,666f726d61746e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), qualifiers:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,7175616c696669657273,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,73656c6563746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6c6576656c:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), convdef:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,636f6e76646566,636f6e766e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,67726f75706964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,67756972656e646572696e67:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6775697374796c65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,74797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType)), changelog:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6368616e67656c6f67,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6368616e676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,63726561746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6465736372697074696f6e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6e6f64656e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,757365726e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,76616c7565707265666978:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), history:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,686973746f7279,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,706b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,636f6d6d656e7473:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,63726561746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6564697464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,6d617864656c65746564726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6d6178726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,707265766d6178:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7265766d6f6465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,757365726e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), reportparam:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TupleType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), transactionstarter:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TupleType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType), keyvaluemapping:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6b657976616c75656d617070696e67,6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6c6f6e676b657931:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c6f6e676b657932:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c6f6e6776616c31:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6c6f6e6776616c32:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6d617070696e6774797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,74696d657374616d70:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), node:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6e6f6465,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,75736572747970656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), rankscore:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,72616e6b73636f7265,6e6f6465316964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e6f6465326964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,72616e6b65726964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6564697464617465:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType,657175616c697479:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DoubleType,6e6f646574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType)), event_nodeid:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6576656e745f6e6f64656964,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,71756575656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e7470617274736571:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6576656e74736571:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,74736e74696d657374616d70:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), valuemap:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,76616c75656d6170,6175786964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,617474726964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c6e6f636f7079:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,646f6d61696e6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c6e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType)), edgetype:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,6564676574797065,6564676574797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6368696c6474797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6465736372697074696f6e:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,697374726565:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,706172656e7474797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,6f776e6572:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType,706172656e7472657669736564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,6368696c6472657669736564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType)), systemsetup:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,73797374656d7365747570,7379736964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,636c6173736964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,706172616d74797065:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,757365726e616d65:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,76616c7565:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), softvalue:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UserType(balluff_production_migrated_v2,736f667476616c7565,6e6f64656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,656467656964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,617474726964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,7175616c6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,726576:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,6d756c74697365716e6f:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,636865636b6964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ShortType,64656c65746564:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BooleanType,646f63:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,70617374:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,70726573656e74:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,756e69746964:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,76616c756537:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)), nulled:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ListType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asked for some help on this one internally, and the consensus is that the tombstone for the dropped column is likely long gone.  If it was still there, any data for that column would be ignored.

One thing to try, would be to re-add the dropped columns with the same name, and drop them again.  That should recreate the column tombstones.

If you don't know the column names, check the schema cql file in the snapshot directory.  It should include the cql needed to restore the columns.

**Edit**

> Isn't it normal that the tombstones are gone after this time?

> Is this something that could happen if our repairs (using Reaper) have (partly) failed?

Yes.  I think the bigger issue is more with the order of events of the column drop and the taking of the snapshot.

> And I actually thought that dropping a column didn't generate a tombstone?

Yes, that was a new learning for me, as well.

> I have successfully added the 3 columns and then the `nodetool refresh` on that table works fine. I can then drop the columns again as you suggest. But won't I just end up in the same situation again then?  So when I run a new backup, problem is back?

As long as you first drop the columns and *then* take the backup, you should be ok.

Comment: Hi Aaron.
I appreciate the feedback, and I am sure I have some lack of knowledge here. Isn't it normal that the tombstones are gone after this time? And I actually thought that dropping a column didn't generate a tombstone?
Is this something that could happen if our repairs (using Reaper) have (partly) failed? We discovered lately that some segments were never repaired due to the "hangingRepairTimeout" of 30 mins was too low.
I would really appreciate if you could explain the problem and why it happens with a bit more detail :)

Comment: I have successfully added the 3 columns and then the "nodetool refresh" on that table works fine. I can then drop the columns again as you suggest. But won't I just end up in the same situation again then? So when I run a new backup, problem is back?
I am confused :)

Comment: And lastly, isn't this a bug?

Comment: @MortenJoenby edit made.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but you're welcome to ask on the user@cassandra.apache.org mailing list.

Comment: Hi Aaron.
I doubt that we did it incorrectly, meaning that the columns were dropped around May 11th 2022, and we run backup every 4 hours. The backup I am trying to restore is from September 5th, so taken 4 months AFTER the column drop.
I really would expect the metadata to be "updated" at this time.
I will try to post this on the user mailing list as well.
Thanks,
Morten

Comment: I also tried the following:
1) set gc_grace_seconds to 0 on table
2) Run: nodetool flush keyspace_name table_name
3) Run: nodetool compact -s keyspace_name table_name
4) set gc_grace_seconds back to 864000 on table

using sstablemetadata still shows the columns. So I assume they will still be present in my backup as well.